# Can a Map that has Groovy String values be (cleanly) converted to Java String

Tags: groovy

I think this is an easy one, though not easy enough for me to figure out yet - so I just decide I would ask....

My code is given a Map in Groovy that is `<String,GString>` and one of the things I need to do is to call a Java method that takes a `<String, String>`.

So I did:

```
def javaMap = new HashMap<String, String>()
passedInProps.each { key, val ->
    javaMap.put(key, val.toString())
}
// pass 'javaMap' to java method here - no problems!
```

Which 'works' fine, but doesn't really seem 'Groovy'.  Can't I use the spread dot operator or something to make this cleaner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try something like :

```
Map jMap = passedInProps.collectEntries { key, value -> 
    [ (key) : value.toString() ] 
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I was after.  However, both of the 'collectMany' methods in the groovy-jdk documentation say they return collections, not Map.  So should I use what you say or should I use 'collectEntries'???

Comment: You're collecting entries for a map.

Comment: Yes - I had started typing one answer then got distracted and put in a different.